# Delphi: DateTimeToStr output with zero time (midnight)

Tags: delphi

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550579/is-datetimetostring-in-delphi-xe5-doesnt-work), but it is unrelated to what I am trying to do.  I have done a lot of research on the Internet and I have determined that Delphi is working as designed or intended, where it omits the time if the time is zero.  I have an application which displays the date & time in a listview, and when the time is midnight, it doesn't show 00:00:00, and therefore making the results look uneven and out of place.

The way I've gotten around this which is still locale independant is to add a microsecond to the time, see sample code:

```
program Test11;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Winapi.Windows;

begin
  try
    Writeln(DateTimeToStr(44167, TFormatSettings.Create(GetThreadLocale)));
    Writeln(DateTimeToStr(44167.00000001, TFormatSettings.Create(GetThreadLocale)));
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

And subsequent output:

```
02/12/2020
02/12/2020 00:00:00
```

The question is - is there a better, more programatically correct way to do achieve this?

Running Delphi XE6

Comment: @nolaspeaker - that then implies a locale - I need my application to be locale independant.

Comment: @nolaspeaker - I appreciate the additional comments, but I have accepted the answer below.  hh:nn:ss.zzz is still specifying a locale format.  For example, the en-us locale shows midnight as 12:00:00 AM - which your example would not have output.

Comment: FWIW you can just call `TFormatSettings.Create` it calls `GetThreadLocale` internally on Windows - bonus effect: cross platform compatibility

Comment: @nolaspeaker, that's incorrect, because time format is locale-dependent as well.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Well then my answer is bad.

Comment: I just got bit by this - very low probability of occurrence, but big impact on downstream parsers.  I don't see how this could reasonably be considered "as designed" and not a bug, though. Especially if the program specifically overrides the format:    `LongTimeFormat := 'hh:mm:ss+0';`   it doesn't seem reasonable to assume that the user would conclude the entire time field will be omitted at 00:00.   Now using FormatDateTime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`FormatDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) function for more control over date time formatting.

```
FormatDateTime('ddddd tt', 44167, TFormatSettings.Create);
```

---

Note: There is no need to call `TFormatSettings.Create(GetThreadLocale)` with locale parameter because plain `TFormattSettings.Create` call will internally use `GetThreadLocale` on Windows platform.

Answer (score -1):

This is "normal" behavior of VCL. Look at the related code from `System.SysUtils` (it is from Seattle, but I think it hasn't much changes since XE6).

```pascal
function DateTimeToStr(const DateTime: TDateTime;
  const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): string;
begin
  DateTimeToString(Result, '', DateTime, AFormatSettings);
end;

procedure DateTimeToString(var Result: string; const Format: string;
  DateTime: TDateTime; const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings);
begin
  ...
  if Format <> '' then AppendFormat(Pointer(Format)) else AppendFormat('C');
  ...

//This is another related part of DateTimeToString.
case Token of
  'C':
    begin
      GetCount;
      AppendFormat(Pointer(AFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat));
      GetTime;
      if (Hour <> 0) or (Min <> 0) or (Sec <> 0) or (MSec <> 0) then
      begin
        AppendChars(' ', 1);
        AppendFormat(Pointer(AFormatSettings.LongTimeFormat));
      end;
    end;
```

If time part of datetime value equals to zero, then only date will be in result string.

If you want always show datetime in single format, better use `FormatDateTime` as suggested by other answers.

Comment: The question already declares that *I have determined that Delphi is working as designed or intended*. So the bulk of this answer simply repeats that. And then the final paragraph refers to the other answer. This feels like it should be a comment rather than an answer.